# Scroll to a specific page in PDF document

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf

I created an app using PDF reader from https://github.com/vfr/Reader.
The source is great, but I cannot find a way to scroll to a specific page. For example, the document has 10 pages and I want to display the 10th page at launching time.
How do I do it?

Comment: Please at least show us that you have tried something. Any code you wrote, any research. Include that in your question.

Comment: if u could show us what u have tried. it would be easy to answer..

Comment: I have tried the below code . Check out my answer and let me know if you have issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer`
 method after this line

```
ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:filePath password:phrase];
```

write the below code

```
[document setPageNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
```